# Cross-Platform C++ Parser Library

Tags: c++, file, parsing, cross-platform

What would a good cross-platform C++ parser for use on a space and tab delimited txt file? I am looking to parse the file and then output a new txt file based off the parsed info.

The input file contains details for a network traffic script with several columns such as Host IP Address, Host Interface, Subnet, etc.

I need to take the information from the input file and create the traffic script in the format that another application requires.

Here is an example of the format for the input file:

```
Hostname    HostIP Area    Host Interface   Number of Routes
test1    128.1.1.1 0.0.0.0       128.100.1.1       100   
test1    128.1.1.2 0.0.0.0
test1    128.1.1.3 0.0.0.0
test2    128.2.2.4 0.0.0.0       128.200.5.6       100
test2    128.2.2.5 0.0.0.0
test2    128.2.2.6 0.0.0.0
```

I am asking for a library that would be ideal to parse this type of data and create a new text file.

Comment: Text parsing is a pretty open-ended question.  What kind of source data do you actually have, and what are you trying to pull out of it?

Comment: Please provide more details about the input format.

Comment: Boost Spirit?
C++ and cross platform.
But agreed with the comments above, what/how do you want to parse?

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I am looking to parse text file that contains both space and tab delimiters. I'm not sure what other info you are looking for or why it should matter, but I updated the question with some details of what the text file will contain.

Comment: There is an example how to write csv parser in AXE: http://www.gbresearch.com/axe/reference.pdf
As long as you have reasonably conforming C++11 compiler (VC10, gcc 4.6) you can use it on any platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple input file like the example you've give, you could write your own just for this file type. You can use the standard C++ classes and build your own file interpreter. Here's a great guide:

[http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

Answer (score 2):

Boost may be a solution. If you simply wish to split data based on spaces and tabs, check out [boost::split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3184031).